# JS not moving side-bar to the left when persona bar is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, dotnetnuke

Have a DNN/Evoq skin based off of this: https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/

Prior to DNN/Evoq 9, the control bar was at the top; no problems.  Now the persona bar is on the left and it causes issues when logged in.  The sidebar doesn't move since it's position is set to fixed.

So I tried adding some JS code to add a class to this sidebar to move the item left an additional 80px; this isn't working.

Any ideas?  Thanks..

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 300px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    background: #415A8A;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    border-right: 2px solid #c88d0c;
}

#sidebar-wrapper.sideadmin {
    left: 380px;
}


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // When persona bar is active, move page right 80px
        $(function () {
            if ($('form').hasClass('personalBarContainer')) $('#sidebar-wrapper').addClass('sideadmin');
        });
    });
</script>

<html>
<body id="Body" style="margin-left: 80px;">
    <form method="post" action="/" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="Form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="ctl15_PersonaBarPanel" class="personalBarContainer">
            .....
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="mm-wrapper">
            .....
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the fact that the PersonaBar is loaded in an Iframe. With the code below you can manipulate that Iframe. It adds an extra class to that Iframe and moves it 80px to the right. It also sets the rest of the page back to the left side of the browser. Maybe this will help you get started.

```
<style>
    .sidebar-wrapper {
        border: 2px solid red;
        position: absolute;
        left: 80px !important;
    }
    .extraBodyClass {
        left: 0px !important;
        margin-left: 0px !important;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#personaBar-iframe").addClass('sidebar-wrapper');
        $("body").addClass('extraBodyClass');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello.. I tried this and it doesn't appear to be working properly; the sidebar isn't moving over when logged in.  Thanks..

Comment: This is a custom skin and not the DNN default skin.  The JS code is based on the controlpanel JS code which would allow the skin to drop down the appropriate amount of space depending on whether the controlpanel was there or not.  Since they moved to the persona bar, I thought it would work as it did before, but it doesn't.